# Use inner select value in outer select

Tags: mysql

Here's a nice, easy question for you all to get more reputation on.

Here's my mysql query:

```
BEGIN

  SELECT
    sID vID,
    sSSN vSSN,
    CONCAT_WS('; ',
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT pCheck) = 0, "Employee had no paycheck data during the month", NULL),
      IF(COUNT(DISTINCT sDate) > 1, "Represents multiple benefit records", NULL)

    ) comments,
    sLocation vLocation
  FROM groups
  WHERE (sSSN, sID) NOT IN (
    SELECT pSSN, pID, pCheck
    FROM vGroups
    WHERE pID = pvID
      AND pDate >= pvStartDate
  )
  AND sID = pID
  GROUP BY sSSN, sID;

  END$$
```

Why do I get an error when trying to use `pCheck` in the outer `SELECT` statement? Is it because it's only being defined further down?

I was thinking perhaps an `AS` after the inner `SELECT` would fix this but I got an error when I tried it, and either way I only want `pCheck`, not `pSSN` or `pID`.

Please, all you nice knowledgeable people out there, is there a way I can use `pCheck` where I need it?

Comment: Please post the task, not the way which you decide to solve it by...

Comment: The task I have is to be able to use `pCheck` in this query. I can't start rewriting the whole method

Comment: This is NOT the  task. The task is "I have the tables ... with DDLs ... and data like ... I need to select ... if ... parameters are ... then desured result for this sample data is ...".

Comment: You may be right as in, this is the **generic** task - but it's not **my** task. Like I said, I can't start rewriting the whole method. It's much bigger than what I posted, I cut out most of it because it wasn't applicable to my question

Comment: You cannot refer to the fields in subquery posessed in WHERE. The only method to solve is to move the subquery from WHERE clause to FROM clause.

Comment: Ok thanks, that was what I wanted to know - if it was possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query there is no outer or inner select query...
You have one query from table groups, and can use only its fields

Your inner query belongs to WHERE clause, so if you want to use vGroups fields in your query you should join groups with vGroups and then use its fields, for example

```
SELECT
    sID vID,
    sSSN vSSN,
    CONCAT_WS('; ',
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT pCheck) = 0, "Employee had no paycheck data during the month", NULL),
      IF(COUNT(DISTINCT sDate) > 1, "Represents multiple benefit records", NULL)

    ) comments,
    sLocation vLocation,
    vGroups.pCheck
  FROM groups
  LEFT JOIN vGroups ON groups.sID = vGroups.pID
  WHERE (sSSN, sID) NOT IN (
    SELECT pSSN, pID, pCheck
    FROM vGroups
    WHERE pID = pvID
      AND pDate >= pvStartDate
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! That left join fixed it

Comment: @Still_learning In that case, there's something you're not telling us, because it's not possible that this query would execute without error.

Comment: @Strawberry Yep, there is something... I didn't copy and paste this code, I just used the general structure of the left join and that worked. Just out of interest though, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Still_learning You cannot have a differing number of arguments in the WHERE and its subsequent IN().

Comment: @Strawberry Oh right, that was a different error that I had commented out while trying to figure this out... But I fixed it after using the join